# How do I get dependent dropdownlist to work?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I have 2 php files. One is called getCategory.php. This file is used to query sql server database to get all categories.

The other is called getSubCategory.php.

This queries the db to select all subcategories associated with categories.

The categoryId is the relationship key between the two.

Then I have a file with 2 dropdownlists.

One with id="cat_id" and the second dropdown has an id of sub_cat.

Our requirement is that you select an option from the category dropdown and the second dropdown, the subcategory dropdown, is populated with values based on your selection from category dropdown.

I have managed to do this successfully in the past with asp.net and classic asp.

I am not sure how to get this to work with php.

Particularly difficult for me atleast is the fact that the category and subcategory are in two separate files as indicated above.

Below is what I have managed to put together so far but your expert assistance is greatly needed to help get this working the correct way.

Thanks alot in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getRecs()
{
    var httpxml;
    try
    {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        // Internet Explorer
        try
        {
            httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            try
            {
                httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    function stateck()
    {
        if(httpxml.readyState==4)
        {
            //alert(httpxml.responseText);
            var myarray = JSON.parse(httpxml.responseText);
            var myarray=myarray.split(",");
            for(j=document.testform.subcat.options.length-1;j>=0;j--)
            {
                document.testform.subcat.remove(j);
            }


            for (i=0;i<myarray.length;i++)
            {
                var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
                optn.text = myarray[i];
                optn.value = myarray[i];
                document.testform.subcat.options.add(optn);

            }
        }
    }
    var url="http://servername/path/getCategory.php";
    var cat_id=document.getElementById('cat_id').value;
    url=url+"?cat_id="+cat_id;
    url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
    httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
    //alert(url);
    httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
    httpxml.send(null);
}
</script>


</head>
<body>

    <h1>
       Requests
    </h1>

    <form>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">New Request</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Existing Request</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Request Details</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Location</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
       <div class="side-by-side clearfix">
        <div>
          <select name="cat_id" id="cat_id" data-placeholder="Choose a category..." class="chosen-select" style="width:500px;" onchange="getRecs();">
            <option value=""></option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat" data-placeholder="Choose a subcategory..." class="chosen-select" style="width:500px;">
            <option value=""></option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div data-role="content">
          <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="  Enter a room..." onfocus="clearText(this)" onblur="restoreText(this)" style="width:493px;color:#999;font-size:9pt;height:20px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </p>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE**

BEGIN - Latest code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCats()
{
    var httpxml;
    try
    {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        // Internet Explorer
        try
        {
            httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            try
            {
                httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    function stateck()
    {
        if(httpxml.readyState==4)
        {
            //alert(httpxml.responseText);
            var myarray = JSON.parse(httpxml.responseText);
            var myarray=myarray.split(",");
            for(j=document.reqform.subcat.options.length-1;j>=0;j--)
            {
                document.reqform.subcat.remove(j);
            }


            for (i=0;i<myarray.length;i++)
            {
                var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
                optn.text = myarray[i];
                optn.value = myarray[i];
                document.reqform.subcat.options.add(optn);

            }
        }
    }
    var caturl="path/getCategory.php";
    caturl=caturl+"&sid="+Math.random();
    httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
    //alert(caturl);
    httpxml.open("GET",caturl,true);
    httpxml.send(null);
}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
function getRecs()
{
    var httpxml;
    try
    {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        // Internet Explorer
        try
        {
            httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            try
            {
                httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    function stateck()
    {
        if(httpxml.readyState==4)
        {
            //alert(httpxml.responseText);
            var myarray = JSON.parse(httpxml.responseText);
            var myarray=myarray.split(",");
            for(j=document.testform.subcat.options.length-1;j>=0;j--)
            {
                document.testform.subcat.remove(j);
            }


            for (i=0;i<myarray.length;i++)
            {
                var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
                optn.text = myarray[i];
                optn.value = myarray[i];
                document.testform.subcat.options.add(optn);

            }
        }
    }
    var url="path/getSubCategory.php";
    var cat_id=document.getElementById('cat_id').value;
    url=url+"?cat_id="+cat_id;
    url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
    httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
    //alert(url);
    httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
    httpxml.send(null);
}
</script>


</head>
<body onload="getCats()">

    <h1>
       Requests
    </h1>

    <form name="reqform" method='POST' action='processRequest.php'>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">New Request</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Existing Request</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Request Details</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Location</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
       <div class="side-by-side clearfix">
        <div>
          <select name="cat_id" id="cat_id" data-placeholder="Choose a category..." class="chosen-select" style="width:500px;" onchange="getRecs();">
            <option value=""></option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat" data-placeholder="Choose a subcategory..." class="chosen-select" style="width:500px;">
            <option value=""></option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div data-role="content">
          <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="  Enter a room..." onfocus="clearText(this)" onblur="restoreText(this)" style="width:493px;color:#999;font-size:9pt;height:20px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </p>
  </div>
```

END - Latest code

```
[{"BuildingDisplay":"132 Mitchell Street Tax Commissioner Office - 132 Mitchell St., SW","BuildingID":"B610012","Address":"132 Mitchell St., SW","City":"Jonesboro","District":"Central","Location":"B610012 132 Mitchell Street Tax Commissioner Office","State":"GA","StreetName":"132 Mitchell St., SW","Zip":"30303","X":2227970.4292704,"Y":1364292.9044986},{"BuildingDisplay":"34 Peachtree Street - 34 Peachtree St.","BuildingID":"B630012","Address":"34 Peachtree St.","City":"Jonesboro","District":"Central","Location":"B630012 34 Peachtree Street","State":"GA","StreetName":"34 Peachtree St.","Zip":"30303","X":2228810.0213674,"Y":1365970.5523757},.....
```

Comment: What problem are you having with the you wrote?

Comment: @Barmar, two problems. One, the category dropdown is not getting populated. Two, I would like to get the url for subcategory as I did with category. This is category: `var url="http://servername/path/getCategory.php";` but I am not even sure I did it correctly which may explain why it isn't populating the dropdown.

Thanks a lot sir for responding.

Comment: `getRecs` should be calling `getSubCategory.php`, not `getCategory.php`. You should call `getCategory.php` from the `window.onload` function.

Comment: @Barmar, can you help sir with the window.onload bit?

Comment: `<body onload="getCats()">` where `getCats()` is a function similar to `getRecs()`, but populates `cat_id` by calling `getCategory.php`.

Comment: @Barmar, do I get rid of these then?

`var cat_id=document.getElementById('cat_id').value;
    url=url+"?cat_id="+cat_id;
    url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();`

Comment: You can get rid of the cat_id parameter, since it doesn't make sense. But you probably still want the sid cache-buster, don't you?

Comment: @Barmar, I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong because none of the dropdowns are getting populated with values.

Do you mind if I posted my latest code for you to take a look at?

Obvioulsy, you know what you are doing.

Comment: Not only do I not mind, I encourage you to update the question with the latest code. Don't delete the old code, though, make it an addition.

Comment: @Barmar, I have updated latest code above.

Thank you sir for your assistance.

Comment: The delimiter between the URL and the parameters is `?`, not `&`. The latter is the delimiter between different parameters.

Comment: In `getCats()` you should be updating `document.reqform.cat_id`, and in `getRecs()` you should be updating `document.reqform.sub_cat`.

Comment: @Sorry sir but is the latest code, top code or bottom code?

Comment: The latest code is at the end, between the `BEGIN Latest` and `END Latest` markers.,

Comment: @Barmar, still not populating any of the dropdowns sir.

Thanks a lot for your patience.

Comment: Are you sure your PHP is returning JSON that matches the way you're processing it? Your code expects that it created a comma-separated string, and then did `echo json_encode($string)`.

Comment: have to leave for the day now, good luck

Comment: @Barmar,

When I comment out httpxm.responseText, I see response like one posted above.

Yet, it is not populating the dropdownlist.

Comment: The JSON you added at the end of your question doesn't look like categories or subcategories. It's an array of objects that contain addresses of buildings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why aren't you using jQuery?
2. In `stateck()`: You make a `JSON.parse` to get a JSON Object but then you do a `split`?
3. Can you give an example how your `httpxml.responseText` looks like?

With jQuery your function `getRecs()` would be:

```
function getRecs() {
    $.get( "getCategory.php", function( data ) {
      // I don't know your JSON Structure, but here you could make someting like:
      $.each(data, function(_key, _value) {
        var opt = $("<option/>");
        opt.attr("text", _value.text);
        opt.attr("value", _value.value);
        $("select").append(opt);
      });
    }, "json" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your jQuery is probably better if I can understand it. Can you please show how to use it to populate not just the category dropdown but also the subcategory?

Comment: `$.get()` makes an HTTP GET Request to the given (1. parameter) url, if this call is finished, your function (2. parameter) is being called with the response text in the `data` variable. The 3. parameter ("json") means, that the response  in `data` isn't a text but a JSON object.
So replace `getCategory.php` with `getSubCategory.php` and change `$("select").append(opt);` to `$("#selectcat").append(opt);` and `$("#selectsubcat").append(opt);` where `selectcat` and `selectsubcat` are the id's of your html select's.